# creating android service for simple radio

Tags: android, android-studio

I've been reading a while and all about services, I'm not all in dev, I'm new to this stuff and wanna learn, as a test I'm trying to make an online radio stream app. I already made it and it works perfect, my only problem is I can't seem to find the way to make the services work or how to do so, I know most of you all are great devs on android and all but just looking for a teacher or someone willing to show me how

this is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
 {
    Button b_play1;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    boolean prepared;
    String stream = "http://73.160.214.181:8000/stream";
    private boolean started;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        startService(new Intent(this, mServices.class));

        b_play1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play1);
        b_play1.setEnabled(false);

        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

        new PlayerTask().execute(stream);

        b_play1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (started) {
                    started = false;
                    mediaPlayer.pause();
                    b_play1.setBackground(getDrawable(play));
                } else {
                    started = true;
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    b_play1.setBackground(getDrawable(pause));

                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        if(started){
            mediaPlayer.pause();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        if(started){
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        if(prepared){
            mediaPlayer.release();
        }
    }



    class PlayerTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean>
    {
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... strings) {
         try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(strings[0]);
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            prepared = true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return prepared;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
        super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);
        b_play1.setEnabled(true);
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

create a service class like

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    MediaPlayer mPlayer;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.laila);
        mPlayer.setLooping(false); // Set looping
    }


   @Override
 public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    mPlayer.start();
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        mPlayer.stop();
    }
}
```

Add below line in your Manifest.xml file

```
<service android:name=".service.MyService" android:enabled="true"/>
```

You can start service by calling

```
 startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
```

and stop service

```
stopService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
```

This is the basic flow how to start and stop a service. You can read more here [Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)

Comment: guess the only thing i did right was the Bind and the xml file. im doing my best to learn, i wanna program for android but im not that good, any books you can recommend would be nice. thanks.

Comment: whats the R.raw ?

Comment: @err0r raw is a resource folder where you can place your media file. Create one folder name **raw** inside **res** folder and place your media file like audio and video file in it.

Comment: Best place to start learning  android is https://developer.android.com/training/index.html also you can check https://www.udacity.com/courses/android. This is the best video tutorial site having many free android tutorials to start with.

Comment: im not doing the app like that, my app just use's the link from my icecast streaming

Comment: i found the problem, i cannot call the service start       with my only play button i have on my mainactivity   startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an Android audio chapter in my book, and in it I present an app that plays music using a background service. 
So here I am going to summarize it and slightly adapt it using your code to show how you should be able to stream from background service. Instead of using the Async task in your Activity, your are going to have a mainActivity that binds to a Service that does the streaming.

First, you need to define the service in your manifest: (obviously use your package name, not mine shown below)

```
<application
<service
android:name="com.wickham.android.musicservice.MusicService"
android:label="Music Service"
android:enabled="true">
</service>
```

Then, you need to bind your Activity to the service. The Activity can be used to control the service, such as starting and stopping the stream: (the following code block go in your Main Activity, that is where you have everything now)

```
// Bind the Service
bindService(new Intent(this,MusicService.class), Scon,Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
// Connect to Service
public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder binder) {
mServ = ((MusicService.ServiceBinder)binder).getServiceInstance();}


// Start the service
Intent music = new Intent();
music.setClass(this,MusicService.class);
startService(music);


// Controlling the service
mServ.resumeMusic();
mServ.pauseMusic();
```

Then, in your service class that will be doing the actual streaming, you can implement it like this: (I did not include the two methods called resumeMusic() and pauseMusic(), but those go in the service and do basically what you had already in your activity.

```
public class MusicService extends Service implements MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener{
        private final IBinder mBinder = new ServiceBinder();
        MediaPlayer mPlayer;
        private int length = 0;
        public MusicService() { }
        public class ServiceBinder extends Binder {
                public MusicService getServiceInstance() {
                return MusicService.this;
                }
        }
        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0){return mBinder;}
        @Override
        public void onCreate () {
                super.onCreate();
                mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                mPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
                mPlayer.setLooping(false);
                mPlayer.setVolume(100,100);
                mPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {
                        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                                onError(mPlayer, what, extra);
                                return true;
                        }
                });
        }
}
```

Hope this can help a little bit.